# system keeps rebooting randomly

Tags: reboot, 23.04

my ubuntu system keeps rebooting randomly ever since I've updated to 23.04. my cpu temp looks fun and I've done a memory check so I think it's software related considering the fact that it just started happening after the update.
this is what I get when I run `journalctl -b -1 -e`

```
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-4654.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Unmounted snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-4654.mount - Mount unit for telegram-desktop, revision 4654.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Stopped target local-fs-pre.target - Preparation for Local File Systems.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Stopped target snapd.mounts-pre.target - Mounting snaps.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Reached target umount.target - Unmount All Filesystems.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-sysusers.service - Create System Users.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Stopped systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Reached target shutdown.target - System Shutdown.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Reached target final.target - Late Shutdown Services.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Finished systemd-poweroff.service - System Power Off.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Reached target poweroff.target - System Power Off.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd-journald[323]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
Apr 21 17:52:32 eloputer systemd-journald[323]: Journal stopped
```

I'm kinda new to linux so I'm not sure how can I troubleshoot it.